# Python SOAP Server using .wsdl file

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to create SOAP Server in python, like in PHP:

```
$server = new WebSoapServer("test.wsdl", $options);
$server->setClass("Webservice_Test");
$server->handle();
```

How to done it, which library whould be best? All i found was developed years ago without any change, and every tutorial of using it don't say how to use wsdl file to generate webservice like in WebSoapServer in php. Can you help me with it?